# How to populate specific rows in a sheet based on specific query or values of cells

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have like 3 different worksheet (3 different University names). And each sheet has 2 columns: Column A contains stream name and Column B contains names of student in that particular stream.

I want to make a 4th sheet where I want to write a query where on the values of 2 cells (i.e, 1st cell contains university name, 2nd cell contain stream name.) should give all the student name matching that criteria. Could you guys help me, this is kinda very imp. and please suggest can I do it using normal Excel formula or should I do it using VBnet.

Thanks a million.....:)

Comment: Show sample **source** data as well as desired result (to be generated based on the shown source data).

Comment: You can do it with an array formula - will post something later

Comment: Okay thanks, Kindly post the exact formula that will be great help.

Answer (score 0):

The formula I'm suggesting is:-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($A$2&"!B:B"),SMALL(IF(INDIRECT($A$2&"!A1:A1000")=$B$2,ROW(INDIRECT($A$2&"!B1:B1000" ))),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

where on my 4th sheet A2 contains the name of the university and B2 contains the name or number of the stream that you're interested in. Change A1:A1000 and B1:B1000 to suit the maximum number of students you expect to see on a sheet. You can use A:A and B:B instead of A1:A1000 and B1:B1000, but it will be rather slow if you do.

The formula should be entered in (say) C2 using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> and pulled down.